# Excel fill corresponding cells using information from another sheet based on one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sorry if the question is a little confusing
I am currently having trouble with excel

I currently have a very simple and rudimentary inventory management system using excel

It contains 2 sheets:

1. itemNames, one sheet contains the name and related details about the item and also a unique ID tagged to each unique item
2. stock, which tracks stock movement based on batches

My issue lies with the fact that i don't want to continually type in the item name into the stock sheet as that will be troublesome(unless i can find a way to have the autocorrect target specific cells from different sheets)

So for example, under the stocks.itemID is in B3 and i put the itemID as "1", it will populate C3 with data from itemNames.name which is on the same row as the value "1" in itemNames

Is that possible in excel? will VBA scripts be needed?

I would love if someone can point me in the right direction as I've tried googling for solutions to no avail

Thank you in advance

Comment: It sounds like a simple `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` / `MATCH` is all that you need.

Comment: @Olly i've updated my post with more details
I'm currently looking at `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX // MATCH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is using `VLOOKUP`. It requires your `ItemID` to come before the other columns in your `ItemNames` sheet.

```
Sht: ItemNames                  Sht: Stock

    A        B                  A       B
1   ID       Name               ID      Name
2   abc123   Hammer             abc123  =VLOOKUP(A2,ItemNames!$A$1:$B$3,1,FALSE) '~~> "Hammer"
3   xyz456   Spanner
```

You can also use `MATCH`. It's slightly more complicated.

```
Sht: ItemNames                  Sht: Stock

    A        B                  A       B
1   Name     ID                 ID      Name
2   Hammer   abc123             abc123  =OFFSET(ItemNames!B1,MATCH(A2,ItemNames!A1:A3,0),0) '~~> "Hammer"
3   Spanner  xyz456
```

I would recommend the `VLOOKUP` approach. It's much simpler.

Comment: Hi Alex, your suggestion works! i did `VLOOKUP` but after more reading i realised that it is better practice to use `MATCH`. So i'm going to go further in depth into these two functions


I have one more question as an excel newbie, how do i apply this formula to the enter column of stock column b, and also be able to reference the itemNames sheet when i add more items to that sheet

Comment: Simply drag the formula down in stock column B. When you add more names to `ItemNames` you have two options. (1) Update `ItemNames!$A$1:$B$3` manually; (2) Extend the range to cover the maximum number of rows you are likely to need e.g.`ItemNames!$A$1:$B$10000`

Comment: Thank you, i got it working, it will lose the `#REF!` but thats ok because i just did a search and replace and got it working!